# Imap subfolders not shown in list command - perhaps acls misconfiguration

Tags: java, access-control-list, imap

My goal is to copy the whole folder structure with all mails from one imap account to another.
The tool I am using for this is **imapcopy** (the java based version from code.google.com since the unix/linux tool packaged with debian doesn't support imaps).

Now, there is one problem: The tool only copies the top-level folders and not the nested ones.
To narrow down the problem I have downloaded the source code of imapcopy and debugged into the code. There I noticed that the `folder.list()` (which is mapped to the `list "%"` imap command) returns an empty list. But when I do a `getFolder(<subfoldername>)` I can access those subfolders. After reading some documentation about the features of imap I think that the problem might be some misconfigured ACLs which prohibit the listing of those folders but allow to read ad write to them.

How should I check this ACLs? which tools do I need for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: It seems that calling `open()` for a particular folder results in an empty list of subfolders for the same folder. By moving the line calling `list()` before the line calling `open()`, **imapcopy** works as expected. I also appended my changed java code to the already existing issue ticket at the [imapcopy](https://code.google.com/p/imapcopy/) project.